# WSGI error deployment Flask app on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, deployment, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy my Flask app on **pythonanywhere** and I have this error:

*Error running WSGI application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto.s3.deletemarker'.*

Knowing that boto and s3 are not part of my code, I installed them anyway but I still get the same error.

*WSGI.py*

```
import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = '/home/jejrhom1/mysite'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from app import app as application  # noqa
```

Could someone please enlighten me? Thank you!

*EDIT* : PROBLEM SOLVED

I am using Python 3.7 and was downloading my modules in a different version, which was resulting in the error. For those who will have the same issue, use :

```
pipversion_python install module_name
```

**Change "version_python" by the Python version used and "module_name" by the module you want to download.**

Comment: `boto` is the Amazon Web Services SDK for Python. I don't know much about pythonanywhere, but it seems likely that their environment utilizes AWS, and is missing this element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @captnsupremo, I'll try to dig a little deeper into that.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- while we do host our systems on AWS, your own code doesn't need to know anything about that, as it's not directly exposed.  Perhaps some package that you do depend on uses boto indirectly?  It might help if you were to post the full stack trace of the exception that you're getting.

Comment: Hello Giles, thanks for the answer! I just solved the issue. I am using Python3.7 and was downloading my modules in different versions, which was leading to the error. Rookie mistake I would say. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear you worked it out!